# I'm a beginner in php and i want to echo this properly but the error says

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\homepage.php on line 235
```

I want to echo my post in my wall if it has a content to post but if the length of my textarea is <0 or above to 160 I want to echo an error then redirect to same page. But if it has a content I want to echo that messages.

```
<?php 

//build query for displaying post messages                                  
$strQuery = "SELECT * FROM freedom_wall ORDER BY id DESC";

// execute
if ($hQuery = $objConnection->query($strQuery)) {
//get data
while($row=$hQuery->fetch_assoc()){
$link_address = "files.php";


?>  
<hr>    
<?php 

$postbody = $_POST['post_msg'];
if (strlen($postbody) > 160 || strlen($postbody) < 1) {
echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
window.alert('Nothing to post!');
window.location.href='homepage.php';
</script>");
} else { //This is where I received the error i'm hard enough in using ' and " with concats
echo   "<br><h4><?php echo $row['username']; ?></h4>
<p><h4><?php echo $row['post_msg']; ?></h4>
<?php echo '<a href='".$link_address."'>".$row["post_file"]."</a>';?>
</p>";
?>

Please help me
```

Comment: you can not open php tag inside php tag.

Comment: I closed the first php tag then I open another php tag. Else can you tell me near where that tag? Sorry for bad english

Comment: use concatenation of string instead of open and close php tag in echo statement. (http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Wait sir I will check

Answer (score 0):

This should fix the issue:

```
<?php $strQuery = "SELECT * FROM freedom_wall ORDER BY id DESC"; ?>
<?php if ($hQuery = $objConnection->query($strQuery)): ?>
    <?php while($row = $hQuery->fetch_assoc()): ?>
        <?php $link_address = "files.php"; ?>
        <hr>
        <?php
            $postbody = $_POST['post_msg'];
            if (strlen($postbody) > 160 || strlen($postbody) < 1) {
                echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                window.alert('Nothing to post!');
                window.location.href='homepage.php';
                </script>");
            } else { 
                echo   "<br><h4>" . $row['username'] . "</h4>
                <p><h4>" . $row['post_msg'] . "</h4>
                <a href='" . $link_address . "'>" . $row["post_file"] . "</a>
                </p>";

            }
        ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you sir it helps me a lot. I gonna study the construction of that code. Sir it produce an error ": syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting end of file in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\homepage.php on line 235"

      }
        ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

This is where the error has been expected to fix.

Comment: ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

Comment: The above code seems alright. You will have to show me your complete code and how you've used the changes i made to know what the error is.

Comment: Hungersoft I posted the whole code including your solution for this page. Please help me. I understand now your construction but still I can't find where that error comes from.

Comment: Remove `<?php }  } ?>` that is after my code. If this still doesn't fix, give me the latest error message and the update the code here as well.

Comment: Sure. Did you already seen my previous post? It contains the whole code.

Comment: Yes, that is why I asked you to remove `<?php } } ?>` from your code and then upload the new code here.

Comment: After I remove your code. It goes to 

`if (strlen($postbody) > 160 || strlen($postbody) < 1) {
                            echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
                            window.alert('Nothing to post!');
                            window.location.href='homepage.php';
                            </script>");`
And having an exception (unlimited loop) on that code

Comment: I will update you with the whole code.

Comment: I believe the code you posted is of the file homepage.php, which means you are loading it over and over and every time it goes to the same part of the loop. Remove `window.location.href='homepage.php';` and then try.

Comment: I remove it. Then it releases this code. `Notice: Undefined index: post_msg in C:\xampp\htdocs\project\homepage.php on line 219`

Comment: The error message clearly describes what the error is, can't you understand that? Add an `isset` function check to make sure `post_msg` is set.

Comment: Also I'm having a problem with my textarea because when I load the `homepage.php` The placeholder in textarea are not displaying. I think it has a whitespace and when I deleted those whitespaces the placeholder will now appear. I already check my value in that textarea  and it was empty but still there are whitespaces.

Comment: I already added that

Comment: I will show you now the code. It was okay. But the whitespaces I can't fix it.

Comment: I don’t know what you mean

Comment: `<div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
             <textarea type="text" name="post_msg" placeholder="Write something" class="form-control">`

This code sir when I go to homepage.php. The Textarea must be display first the Placeholder. But it displays so many whitespaces.

Comment: That is because your closing tag `</textarea>` has one empty line above it. Place the tag `</textarea>` on the same line as `<textarea type="text" name="post_msg" placeholder="Write something" class="form-control" required="">`.

Comment: Thank you sir for helping me. What can I do for you? I'm just a newbie user here at stackoverflow. When I visiting profiles I can see reputations.

Comment: You can accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have not closed curly braces of all starting curly braces. Use below code that I have fixed for you.

```
<?php 

//build query for displaying post messages                                  
$strQuery = "SELECT * FROM freedom_wall ORDER BY id DESC";

// execute
if ($hQuery = $objConnection->query($strQuery)) {
//get data
while($row=$hQuery->fetch_assoc()){
    $link_address = "files.php";


    ?>  
    <hr>    
    <?php 

    $postbody = $_POST['post_msg'];
    if (strlen($postbody) > 160 || strlen($postbody) < 1) {
    echo ("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Nothing to post!');
    window.location.href='homepage.php';
    </script>");
    } else { //This is where I received the error i'm hard enough in using ' and " with concats
    echo   "<br><h4><?php echo $row['username']; ?></h4>
    <p><h4><?php echo $row['post_msg']; ?></h4>
    <?php echo '<a href='".$link_address."'>".$row["post_file"]."</a>';?>
    </p>";

    }
}
}
?>
```